# Opening PDF with default Reader version of Acrobat, not non-default Pro, in Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, pdf

I have VBA code that opens a PDF file based on user input.

I have installed on my computer both Adobe Acrobat Pro DC and Adobe Acrobat Reader DC.

I have set Adobe Acrobat Reader DC as the default program for PDFs.

When VBA opens the PDF, it opens in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC.

```
 Private Sub BarCode_AfterUpdate()

     Dim BarCode As String    

     Application.FollowHyperlink BarCode & ".pdf"

 End Sub
```

Any ideas on how to have it opened with Adobe Acrobat Reader DC?

Comment: You're basically just clicking a link.  It's not opening in Access for the same reason web pages don't open in Access.  They're not supposed to.  You'll need a lot more code than that to get a PDF into Access.  Try Google, there's some examples around here and there.  Might not be easy.

Answer (score 0):

It's really not as difficult as you may think. You will just need to grab the full path to the application you want to use, and then call `Shell` to do the work for you.

```
Private Sub BarCode_AfterUpdate()

    Const appPath$ = "C:\somePath\adobeFileName"
    Dim BarCode As String    

    Shell appPath & " " & BarCode & ".pdf"

End Sub
```